# Sorting XML output

Tags: php

Here is the PHP im using to read XML:

```
            $url = "images.xml";
            $xmlstr = file_get_contents($url);
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);               
            foreach ($xml->image as $image) {
                $id = $image->id;
                $link =  $image->href;
                $src = $image->source;
                $title = $image->title;
                $alt = $image->alt;
                echo "<a href='$link'><img src='$src' alt='$alt' title='$title' /></a>";
            }
```

The XML contains an ID: `$id = $image->id;`

I need to sort the output by that ID. How can I do this within the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

if id is unique i will do something like

```
<?php

$url = "images.xml";
$xmlstr = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);  
$images = array();             
foreach ($xml->image as $image) {
    $id = $image->id;
    $images[$id]['id'] = $id;
    $images[$id]['link'] =  $image->href;
    $images[$id]['src'] = $image->source;
    $images[$id]['title'] = $image->title;
    $images[$id]['alt'] = $image->alt;
}

ksort ($images);
foreach ($images as $image){
    echo "<a href='".$image['link']."'><img src='".$image['src']."' alt='".$image['alt']."' title='".$image['title']."' /></a>";
}
?>
```

And if id is not unique then try this

```
<?php

$url = "images.xml";
$xmlstr = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);  
$images = array();
$ids = array();

foreach ($xml->image as $image) {

    $images[]['id'] = $image -> id;
    $images[]['link'] =  $image->href;
    $images[]['src'] = $image->source;
    $images[]['title'] = $image->title;
    $images[]['alt'] = $image->alt;
    $ids[] = $image -> id;
}

array_multisort($ids, SORT_ASC, $images);

foreach ($images as $image){
    echo "<a href='".$image['link']."'><img src='".$image['src']."' alt='".$image['alt']."' title='".$image['title']."' /></a>";
}
?>
```

These are some quick ones. But these will do the job.